# When I pin a custom tile for my app to the Windows Phone 8 start screen how can I control the background color?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

When the user pins my app to their start screen I would like to provide my own custom background color rather than use the accent color currently in use.  I thought this would work:

```
<Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateIconic>
          <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\SmallTile.png</SmallImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <IconImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\MediumTile.png</IconImageURI>
          <Title></Title>
          <Message></Message>
          **<BackgroundColor>#FFFB8102</BackgroundColor>**
          <HasLarge>True</HasLarge>
          <LargeContent1></LargeContent1>
          <LargeContent2></LargeContent2>
          <LargeContent3></LargeContent3>
          <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false" />
        </TemplateIconic>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
```

When I pin the tile in the emulator currently one of two situation arises:
  If provide a transparent background all I see my image, but the fill color is the accent
  If I provide my image with the background color baked into the image, I get a while blob surrounded by the accent color.

Please keep in mind this is a Windows Phone 8 app, not Phone 7. Far as I know, there is no ApplicationTile image that I can specify.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. You cant specify the AA values of the ARGB when you provide the background color. Too tired

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure this out either! I was including the AA values as well.